# Linux User Space application for RTC-DS1307

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I cross compiled the [rtc-ds1307](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1307.c) driver for an arm based board and Used eeprog utility to read and write to its timing/general purpose registers. Now i want to make a simple USERSPACE app that displays the time continuously. How will my application talk to the driver? Plz tell me the software flow to do this... thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an RTC class device, you can find an example in [Documentation/rtc.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt)

Answer (score 1):

There are good explanations and examples of how to use embedded-linux RTC Real Time Clock hardware [here](https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_RTC_Real_Time_Clock_hardware).